# React App redirects to route "/" when I try to navigate by changing url manually

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am creating a React app, that stores the users role (there are two possible roles 0, and 1 which are being used for conditional rendering) in a "global" React Context. The role gets assigned upon login. I am also using React Router to handle Routing, and wrote a ProtectedRoute component. My Problem is the following: When I am navigating via the NavBar all works perfectly fine, but when I enter e.g. /home into the url I get redirected to the LoginPage(which is the standard route when the role is not set to 0 or 1) and I can not access the other Routes anymore. However, the user does not get logged out (The session in the database is not being deleted), the app just seems to forget the global state "role", which is used to determine whether the user is allowed to access the individual routes. I am afraid my knowledge of the DOM and Router is too limited to solve this problem.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
          <NavigationBar />
          <AuthContext.Consumer>
            {context => (
              <React.Fragment>
                {!context.isAuthenticated() ? <Jumbotron/> : null}
              </React.Fragment>
            )}
          </AuthContext.Consumer>
          <Layout>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={() => <LandingPage />} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/home" component={Home} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/about" component={About}/>
              <ProtectedRoute path="/account" component={Account} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/calender" component={Calender} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/xyz" component={Xyz} />
              <ProtectedRoute path="/wasd" component={wasd} role={0} />
              <Route component={NoMatch} />
            </Switch>
          </Layout>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}


export default App;
```

```
export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const { isAuthenticated, getRole } = useContext(AuthContext);

  if (rest.role === 0) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          getRole() === 0 ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/404",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  } else if (rest.role === 1) {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          getRole() === 1 ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/404",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={props =>
          isAuthenticated() ? (
            <Component {...props} />
          ) : (
            <Redirect
              to={{
                pathname: "/",
                state: {
                  from: props.location
                }
              }}
            />
          )
        }
      />
    );
  }
};
```

```
import React from "react";

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

export default AuthContext;
```

```
class AuthProvider extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      role: 2, //none=2
      name: "",
      email: ""
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{
          state: this.state,
          isAuthenticated: () => {
            if (this.state.role === 1 || this.state.role === 0) {
              return true;
            }
            return false;
          },
          setRole: newRole =>
            this.setState({
              role: newRole
            }),
          getRole: () => {
            return this.state.role;
          },
          setName: newName =>
            this.setState({
              name: newName
            }),
          getName: () => {
            return this.state.name;
            },
          setEmail: newEmail =>
            this.setState({
              email: newEmail
            }),
          getEmail: () => {
            return this.state.email;
            },
        }}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthProvider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are entering the url directing into the browser, React will reload completely and you will lose all state whether 'global' or otherwise. The most likely scenario is that your router is trying to validate your ability to view a component before you have your auth data.

You don't include how you get your auth session from the database, but even if you refetch the auth session, there is going to be a period where your app has mounted, but you don't have the response yet. This will cause your protected route to believe you are unauthorized, and redirect to the fallback path.

Try adding a check either inside your protected route or before the router itself, that blocks rendering until your auth data is loaded. Although upon reading your question again, it seems like you may not be refetching your logged in user at all.

Comment: This is exactly what I thought when I read through the question. If they aren't storing authentication/session data in something that persists, every time the browser is refreshed they'll be logged out. If you look at ProtectedRoute if isAuthenticated() is false it'll redirect to "/".

Comment: Yes, and the fact that they can't get to the other protected routes after the redirect suggests even stronger that they aren't re-fetching the auth data on page load. My first thought was just that they didn't account for time between auth request and response, cause thats a mistake I've made a few times...

Comment: Yup, and there is no mention of cookies or other storage so without storing it or re-fetching it, the authentication data is wiped on reload and then redirects. Might be helpful to get a link to some working code to see how it works...?

Comment: First of all thank you two for your answers. This is part of a university project and me and my team never used React before, nor did we ever create any type of backend. As of now the context gets set once the user presses login on the landing page on route "/". I was not aware, that it will be reset also with every refresh. So your suggestion is to store the session in a localStorage and check it against the sessions in the DB with every call of Pr.Route? Wouldn't that result in a lot of fetching? Or could I use useEffect to only fetch the data everytime the App.js mounts again. Thank you

Comment: I'd fetch the session data when your top level component mounts like you said. No need to do it in every route change. Unless you have special logic like timeouts (which it doesn't appear is the case), your session data will only change when you log in or log out. So that means you can get your session once at the beginning and trust it from there on until you do one of those two actions again.

Comment: Since my index.js looks like this ReactDOM.render(<AuthProvider><App /></AuthProvider>, document.getElementById("root")); my top-level component would be AuthPrivider right? Because I implemented the fetch inside of App.js and it happens exactly what was stated above. I am now able to retain my global context states (which is good), but because they first need to be refetched, my protected routes will always first redirect to "/".

Comment: Yes, thats kinda what I was getting at in the third paragraph. I don't know how you're fetching it, but you'll need to keep track of whether its loading somehow, and do some kind of `if (!loading) { ...render your app } else { ...render loading graphic`. Doing this will stop your router from being rendered until you have the data needed to route correctly.

Comment: It might be easiest to accomplish by putting the router in its own component and doing the check there. But thats up to you

Comment: I also wouldn't worry too much about it being at the very top level. Just high enough to be called anytime your app loads. Inside App would be sufficient.